# Point of passing address and size in functions

Tags: c++

I am doing socket programming in C++ and i see a lot of functions that take structure pointers as well as sizes. For instance,

```
struct sockaddr dest;
//fill dest
sendto(dgram_socket, secret_message, len, 0, &dest, sizeof dest);
```

Whats the point of passing size of a fixed length structure (sockaddr) when the function can clearly interpret it from the type?

Comment: Often this pattern is to allow for future enhancement, e.g. a hypothetical `sockaddr2` structure that the function can distinguish using the size parameter.

Comment: @therainmaker - no. That doesn't happen.

Comment: @Olaf: Re your edit: This looks like pure C code, so removing the [c++] tag instead seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: @MartinR: The question text clearly states C++, so I left the C++ tag. However, OP might rethink his decision and change text and tag.

Comment: @Olaf: OK, I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because actually sockaddr is only placeholder data type here. 
The actual data structure that you pass may differ. For example, address structures for IPv4 and IPv6 differ in content and length. And that's the point of passing structure size.

In general, this is widely used technique. Either size is passed as additioanl parameter or size member is included directly to the structure (typically, as its very first member). This allows the receiving function to distinguish between different known versions of that structure, in the situations, when API changes over the time and new members are added, but still programs alrady compiled with older API defintions have passing strutures with actual size less than it is in the most recent one. This is typical technique faced in the Windows API - many Windows native structures have something like `DWORD cbSize` in them.

Comment: This is correct. I might add: long live sockaddr_storage (SOCKADDR_STORAGE in Windows)

Comment: Wouldnt it have been better to have a version int or a enumerated version? Size seems to be a bad way to determine version. What if similar structures in two different versions have the same size?

Comment: No, this is nort "random" process. API provider (if it is normal adequte API provider, this incldes major companies like Micrsoft) publishes certain well-established and quality-assured version. If API provider chooses to use this method, he ensures than there will be no such collisions, and API can alaways distinguish version using certain known structure sizes. So probablity of this, altough exists, is very low, and like if such defect is faced, it will be quickly found and fixed.

Comment: If you design your own API, it is up to you, how to distinguish. But method with structure size is has an advantage: because structure size is filled manually, if you choose enum, you need to change your client code each time structure defintion changes, and you want to use autmatically newest one. In case with size tag, you don't change code, you always have something like `s.cbSize = sizeof(s);` and that's all. so although this may seem harder to maintain to API provider, it is easier to use for the end-user.

Comment: Sometimes you do not care about what is actually in the structure but just want to copy it and pass it further. Then knowing the size becomes important (and that way you can copy structures you didn't know about in advance). Knowing the version (without knowing the size as well) is no help in that case, because if you don't know the version, you still don't know the size (and the only thing you can do then is to fail).

Comment: Yes, this is another reason why size may be more helpful than version. Although, if you have version you may map it to the size, it is simpler soluton to have size directly.

Answer (score 2):

The `sockaddr` structure is not actually fixed in size - different types of socket need different sizes of address information (e.g. IPv4 or IPv6).

So in this particular case it is actually useful and necessary to specify the length of the actual `sockaddr` that you have.

See for example http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html.